# SLIME not loading from Emacs

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I've recently updated SLIME from `package-list-packages` in Emacs. However, when I try to run it using `M-x slime`, I get this:

```
(progn (load "/home/koz/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/tmp/slime.3081"))

* 
; loading #P"/home/koz/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/swank-loader.lisp"
;; 
;; Error while compiling /home/koz/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/swank/backend.lisp:
;;   Failed to find the TRUENAME of /home/koz/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/swank/backend.lisp:
;;     No such file or directory
;; Aborting.
;; *
```

I still have a REPL afterwards, but I think this is very strange, and I'd like to know what's going on and why.

Comment: What kind of Lisp are you using?

Comment: @echristopherson: SBCL.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error using that version of SLIME and SBCL 1.2.1. Perhaps downgrading SLIME would help.

Comment: Oh well, guess I'll have to try that, then. Probably should log a bug or something with the maintainer of SLIME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by losing the swank sub-directory in your slime folder. To fix it, you can simple download [slime](https://github.com/slime/slime) from github and copy the folder `swank` to your slime installed path, for your situation is `/home/koz/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/` then restart your slime. it will be load correctly.

Answer (score 5):

On [Freenode's #lisp channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#lisp), I talked to one person who agreed that the current version of SLIME in MELPA (20140913.730) is broken. On my system, the whole $HOME/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20140913.730/swank/ directory is missing, which presumably is why it can't compile Lisp files found therein.

Other members of the channel suggested installing SLIME from Quicklisp; I did that and it worked, although the SLIME version there is slightly older (dated 2014-08-01). Here is what I did (I didn't already have Quicklisp installed); adjust to match your system and preferences:

1. Uninstall SLIME from Emacs's package list (do `M-x list-packages`, go to the line for SLIME, press <kbd>d</kbd>, then press <kbd>x</kbd>).
2. Visit http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ and download the file in the green box (in my case, it went in ~/Downloads).
3. Upgrade SBCL to 1.2.2 or later. This is probably overkill.
4. Launch `sbcl`.
5. Evaluate `(load "~/Downloads/quicklisp.lisp")`.
6. Evaluate `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)`; optionally, if you don't want it to go in ~/quicklisp, add `:path "~/.quicklisp/"` (substituting whatever directory you actually do want it installed in).
7. Install SLIME and SWANK by evaluating `(ql:quickload "swank")`.
8. Optional: evaluate `(ql:add-to-init-file)` to patch your .sbclrc to always load Quicklisp in SBCL.
9. Exit SBCL with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
10. Adjust your Emacs config file as shown in [SLIME's readme](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/master/README.md). For the path entry, use `"~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-2.9"` (adjusted for whatever path you installed Quicklisp in).
11. Restart Emacs and `M-x slime` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Was just looking for the exact same answer.

I found that removing the original slime package was necessary (M-x list-packages, cursor over Slime, d to mark then x to remove)

Comment: @tomwalker Thanks. I've edited that into the answer.